# How to sort lines in a text file alphabetically with gedit

Tags: gedit

With Ubuntu's gedit text editor how can I sort lines in a text file alphabetically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*answer for gedit 3.10.4 - ubuntu 14.04 && gedit 3.18.3 - ubuntu 16.04*

you'll first have to install a plugin for gedit. it just takes a few clicks and no reboot.

1. Open gedit
2. Click **Edit**, select **Preferences**
3. Click **Plugins**, check **Sort**
4. Open the text file you want to work with or be sure changes are saved before you test it as you're unable to undo anything after sorting with gedit. (*update - it seems that changes can be reverted in 16.04, not sure since what gedit version*)
5. If you want to sort a portion of the file, highlight what you want sorted else leave all selected by default.
6. (*gedit 3.10.4 - ubuntu 14.04*) Click **Edit**, Click **Sort...**, Click **Sort**

   (*gedit 3.18.3 - ubuntu 16.04*) Click **Tools**, Click **Sort...**, Click **Sort**